# Why a where with only column name, without equals a value is not a syntax error in MySQL

Tags: mysql

Why a query like this is not a syntax error? I have a SQL Server background, i was really surprised.

`SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE id`

I thought it verify if it has value, but the behaviour is not consistent, with id it returns where it has an id, but with name it doesn't return anything:

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/enWGyAW4BtLC64PVzkbTVK/0

Comment: id could be a boolean value in which case it's valid syntax.

Comment: `where true...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL has some behavior that is not compliant with standard ANSI SQL. In this case, MySQL treats an integer zero value as `false`, and any integer non-zero value as `true`. In standard SQL, integers are not the same as booleans, but in MySQL they are.

When you run a query `WHERE id`, it returns rows where `id <> 0`.

When you run a query `WHERE name`, it evaluates the string as an integer, which means to take the numeric value of leading digit characters, if any, and ignoring any following non-digit characters. If there are no leading digits, then the integer value of a string is 0.

When you run a query `WHERE name`, it returns rows only if the string stored in that column has non-zero leading digits. In your example `'outro'`, it only has non-digits, so the value is zero, and it fails to satisfy the condition.

MySQL is behaving as designed, but this is not standard SQL.